# Sorting Python OrderedDict in "heavily nested" structure

Tags: python, sorting, nested, ordereddictionary

I have the following Python dictionary and I'm trying to sort it as an OrderedDict.

```
fruits = {
    "apple": {
        "details": {
            "color": "green", 
            "dim": 100
        },
        "types": {
            "Akane": {
                "taste": "acceptable",
                "sort": 1
            },
            "McIntosh": {
                "taste": "delicious",
                "sort": 0
            }, 
            "Ambrosia": {
                "taste": "ok",
                "sort": 1
            }
        }
    },         
    "pear": {
    }, 
    "banana": {
    }, 
}
```

Basically I want to sort the different appleTypes within that subdictionary by the "sort" value of each appleType.
In the end the ordered dictionary ideally should look like this:

```
fruits_sorted = {
    "apple": {
        "details": {
            "color": "green", 
            "dim": 100
        },
        "types": {
            "Akane": {
                "taste": "acceptable",
                "sort": 1
            },
            "Ambrosia": {
                "taste": "ok",
                "sort": 1
            },
            "McIntosh": {
                "taste": "delicious",
                "sort": 0
            }
        }
    },         
    "pear": {
    }, 
    "banana": {
    }, 
}
```

I've been playing around with the sorted function, but I couldn't quite get it right, I'm not sure how to implement the sorting in that nested structure.

```
fruits_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is very close; you need to have:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

apple_types = fruits['apple']['types']
types_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(apple_types.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]['sort']))
```

Now, `types_sorted` has the apple types in the sorted order you wanted. You can put it back into the original dictionary if you wish.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you! I’m having an issue now.
'sort' can either be 1 or 0 and each item in types is coming in an arbitrary order. I need an alphabetical sort on top of it too, for that I would like to use the key of each type, e.g. 'Akane' (with the 1s and 0s I cannot achieve a „solid“ sorting, with every execution of my code there would be differences).
I know that I can do something like:
`types_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(apple_types.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[1]['sort'])))`
This causes the second sort not to work - is this because it's including these two sort conditions in a single sort?